# Terminal loads but never opens

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

I followed a useless tutorial to install termite. It didn't work out and neither does my usual terminal operate now.

I've tried to reinstall gnome-terminal through various means. However, the terminal just doesn't open. It runs as a process for a few minutes and is then shut off. I have removed termite from my system. Is there a solution to this? Other answers are somehow not helpful.

Comment: How did you make your installation when you don't have a terminal? E.g. how did you "reinstall gnome-terminal"? If you now have a terminal, can you share the output from this terminal command  `dpkg -l | grep gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: This question has at least three duplicates (with answers) here on askubuntu. Enter the search terms `termite gnome-terminal` to the search bar.

Comment: I downloaded terminator. Still, I want gnome-terminal again.